# How to go back in initial selection after google apps script macro?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

Running the macro I've written changes the selection and the sheet that was active before. I'd like to come back to this at the end.

I add at the beginning

```
var initialsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
```

at the end

```
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(initialsheet), true);
```

this works to reselect initial sheet but I don't know how to reselect the initial range
at the beggining I wrote

```
 var initialrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange();
```

How can I reselect it a the end ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I believe what you are doing is trying to expand on a recorded macro.  I would advise you learn the [Spreadsheet Object Model](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) instead.  The macro recorded keeps track of your keyboard input so that's why there are so many "Activate" commands.  The Object Model doesn't do any of that.

Answer (score 1):

When you link google docs with google sheet, when You add a new answer to the docs it fills a tab 'Answers to Form 1', but if other tabs refer to it with a formula, they are not updated. My solution is to write a macro that forces the update.

Here the update of the tab 'Repas' who countains formulas referring to 'Answers to form 1'

@TheWizEd,
Thank you for your interest, you wrote : the macro recorded keeps track of your keyboard input so that's why there are so many "Activate" commands.
I've tried to suppress activate as follows

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var repas = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Repas")
repas.getRange('A2:R2').autoFill(repas.getRange('A2:R200'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
```

Works fine